# How to plot my data in order?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, time-series

I have data that at every time step adds or takes away from list `x` and list `y`. At every time step the `Length[x]` and `Length[y]` are appended to `size={Length[x],Length[y]}`.

I want to plot the length of these two lists over time, but when I plot it

```
ListLinePlot[size, PlotRange -> Full]
```

it gives a strange overlapping plot that isn't over time, recommendations?

Comment: size = {{2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 3}, {5, 4}, {6, 5}};
ListPlot[Transpose[size], PlotRange->Full]

Answer (score 1):

Since you are talking about `TimeSeries`, you might consider using [`TemporalData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemporalData.html?q=TemporalData):

```
(* using Bill's example *)
size = { {2, 3}, {3,2}, {4,3}, {5,4}, {6,5}};

TemporalData[ Transpose @ size, Automatic ] // ListLinePlot
```

Note that using [`Transpose`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html?q=Transpose) does make your data a collection of two time series. You can, of course, also have your data be interpreted as a time series of 2-dimensional data:

```
TemporalData[ size, Automatic, ValueDimensions -> 2 ] // ListLinePlot

(* will give the same result as above *)
```

[image: Time Series Plot]